# Adding and displaying new column from wp_posts table

Tags: while-loop, wordpress

I have added a column in the Wordpress `wp_posts` table.

How can I display this column like `the_title()`, `the_content()`.  My new column name is `web_url`.

Comment: Editing core tables is a bad habit. An update can banish your changes. Use `postmeta` table for additional data storage, or create a new table if it not providing you the solution.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) "Help me please" and "Thanks" are never part of a good question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you shouldn't edit core WP tables, especially that what you want to achieve is quite easy using Custom Fields (more information [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)).

You could create new custom field called `web_url` for each post and then display it using the following function: `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'web_url', true);`